# Creating different types from an unknown sequence, in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Assuming a function that "gets" a sequence of information (e.g. a list of characters), and shall create different types from it, where its type depends on the input sequence, which represents the content - and assuming the types are already given.

```
numFromString :: [Char] -> ???
```

I suppose there is several possibilities.

My first idea is to use a type parameter.

```
main :: IO ()
main =
    do
        sLine <- getLine
        print $ numFromString sLine

numFromString :: (Show a, Read a) => String -> (Maybe a)
numFromString ('I':'n':'t':'e':'g':'e':'r':rs) = Just ((read rs) :: Integer)
--                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this does not work
numFromString ('I':'n':'t':rs) = Just ((read rs) :: Int)
numFromString _ = Nothing
```

...but we cannot just provide an Integer where a type variable is expected or can we?.

My second idea is to use type class

```
main :: IO ()
main = 
    do
        sLine <- getLine
        print $ ((numFromString sLine) :: (Maybe Integer))
        --                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ I have to decide in advance which type I want to get

class (Show a, Read a) => XClass a where
    numFromString :: String -> (Maybe a)

instance XClass Int where
    numFromString ('I':'n':'t':rs) = Just ((read rs) :: Int)
    numFromString _ = Nothing

instance XClass Integer where
    numFromString ('I':'n':'t':'e':'g':'e':'r':rs) = Just ((read rs) :: Integer)
    numFromString _ = Nothing
```

...but this doesnt work as well, when we use numFromString, do we?.

My third idea is to use a sum kind of data type.

```
main :: IO ()
main =
    do
        sLine <- getLine
        print $ numFromString sLine

data X = XInt Int | XInteger Integer | XNone
    deriving Show

numFromString :: String -> X
numFromString ('I':'n':'t':'e':'g':'e':'r':rs) = XInteger (read rs)
numFromString ('I':'n':'t':rs) = XInt (read rs)
numFromString _ = XNone
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Would generic programming help?

How would it look like?

Comment: Your sum type idea looks like the right approach to me.

Comment: You are correct regarding your first attempt. A return type of `Maybe a` means the *caller* gets to choose the type `a`; the function has to be prepared to return *any* type, not just a from a set *it* wants to support.

Comment: The edit changes the question fairly significantly. The accepted way to deal with such things on SO is to open a fresh question, rather than dramatically changing an existing one, especially after there are answers. If you do decide to follow that route, I encourage you to include a few more details about what the types in the library look like, what you're trying to achieve, and why you feel stuck with those two things. (As it stands, your edit isn't really *answerable* without that information.)

Comment: @DanielWagner, OK, I rolled back to the original question. May be, I am looking for something that cannot be achieved, at all. The line "data X = XInt Int | XInteger Integer | XNone" looks a kind of redundant to me. It smells for a solution. So far, I tried to understand whether type families, GADTs, generic programming would make it more elegant (low effort, generic, not redundant and maintainable). For now, even though I didnt fully understand type families, and generic programming, I am going with the sum type approach.

Answer (score 8):

Your sum type approach looks like the right way to me.

For examples of this in the wild:

- The first character of a JSON document determines a type -- `{` for objects, `[` for lists, `"` for strings, etc. `aeson`, a popular Haskell JSON parser, uses [a sum type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.5.6.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Value) that can represent each of these.
- An almost identical situation is involved in parsing CBOR. `cborg` uses [a sum type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cborg-0.2.5.0/docs/Codec-CBOR-Term.html#t:Term) to capture all the possibilities.
- The Smart Games Format can represent the record of moves from a variety of games. The kind of information needed to store a move varies from game to game; the `sgf` library uses [a sum type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sgf-0.1.3.1/docs/Data-SGF-Types.html#t:GameTree) to capture the possibilities.

...and so on.